# Knowing on which ForkJoinPool my RecursiveTask is going to be executed on

Tags: java, jvm, fork-join

I'm having a hard time understanding how to make sure I'm running my forked tasks in my own `ForkjoinPool`, instead of having it use the common pool, which I assume is what happens when you don't indicate in which thread-pool you want to run.

Looking at the code below, it seems there's no link between my `fjp` instance and the newly instantiated `FibonacciCalculator` objects. This makes me assume my `fjp` is not actually being used for the subtasks. How to do that?

```
object FJPoolApp extends App {
  val fjp = new ForkJoinPool()
  println(fjp.submit(new FibonacciCalculator(10)).get)
}

class FibonacciCalculator(k : Int) extends RecursiveTask[Int] {
  override def compute(): Int = {
    if (k <= 1) k
    else {
      val left = new FibonacciCalculator(k-1).fork()  <-- where is this being run?
      val right = new FibonacciCalculator(k-2).fork() <-- where is this being run?
      left.join() + right.join()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the documentation of [`ForkJoinTask#fork()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork()) says:

> Arranges to asynchronously execute this task **in the pool the current task is running in** *[emphasis added]*, if applicable, or using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` if not `inForkJoinPool()`.

And here's the documentation of [`ForkJoinTask#inForkJoinPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#inForkJoinPool()):

> Returns true if the current thread is a `ForkJoinWorkerThread` executing as a `ForkJoinPool` computation

Since you execute your primordial `FibonacciCalculator` in a `ForkJoinPool`, the forks created inside the task are also executed in that *same* pool.

Comment: I see. It's IMO an unfortunate API decision, though. It would have been preferable to have the `fork()` taking an optional FJP object and make the currently implicit, explicit. This is what Scala does with its `Future`s.

Comment: I disagree, though that's obviously just my opinion as well. The `ForkJoinTask` is not supposed to care what pool it's being executed in, that's the job of the code which initially executes it. Whether correct or not, I believe the designers understood the most common case to be forking within the same pool, and having to make that explicit every time would be a hassle. If you need to execute in a different pool you can always just pass the task to that pool instead of calling `fork()` (you'd have to have a reference to the other pool anyway).